# Computer fails to sleep when booting from a NVMe SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, sleep, pci-express, nvme

Whenever I'm trying to put my PC to sleep, the screen goes blank but a power indicator stays on and all fans keep on working.
I have a NVMe SSD installed on a PCIe card, and OS is installed on this disk. This problem is only happening when I put it to a PCIe 3.0 slot; when I move it to a PCIe 2.0 slot, the problem goes away but the disk works at half max speed.
Any ideas how to fix this problem?

UPD my motherboard is this one [GA-Z97MX-Gaming 5](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4968#ov)

UPD2 after removing the video card, the results are the same for both PCIe 3.0 slot, i.e. PC shuts down incorrectly instead of sleeping.

Comment: Is it happening temporarily.?

Comment: @Kushagra, it's happening always when the PCIe adapter is in a PCIe 3.0 slot, in 100% cases.

Comment: When the computer fails to enter standby, is it still responsive (ie. can you wake it again)?

Comment: @Daniel B, no. It gets stuck forever with monitor and keyboard off, and case fans on.

Comment: So basically it crashes. Please add the exact motherboard model you’re using to the question and indicate which of the PCIe slots you tried is working or not.

Comment: @Daniel B, there are only 3 full-sized slots there, and the 1st is occupied with a video card.

Comment: I see. Do you have a CPU with integrated GPU? In that case, you could try it in the graphics card’s slot, both without the graphics card and with the graphics card in slot 2. It most likely won’t help, but it’s worth a try. It appears to be an issue with how the PCIe lanes are routed. The PCIe 2.0 slots are both connected to the chipset while the PCIe 3.0 ports are connected directly to the CPU.

Comment: @Daniel B, the result with the 1st slot is similar but a bit different. The PC shuts down instead of sleeping, and starts with the "windows didn't shut down properly" message on the next startup.

Comment: Please [run `powercfg -energy`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/) with the SSD in the PCIe 3.0 slot and post the generated report.

Comment: @harrymc, it's the same as the results when using v2.0 slot.

Comment: Posting the results might help.

Comment: Reminder: Please post the results of `powercfg -energy` so we could have some information for analyzing the problem.

Comment: Seems you guys are already on the right track, so please stick to it. As a next step, only If it is difficult to track, as a next step
- Is there a disk indicator and does it stay on?
- Did you trace/view the system related events using Windows Event Viewer (taking time stamps as the guide)? 
- SSD type and OS. Because OS on ssd running NVMe and hardware do not suite for all boot and usage scenarios. There are compatibility issues/requirements, pcie bandwidth concerns and video/video driver issues depending on the OS.

Comment: @harrymc, most likely a driver bug.